# The loader.js addon is missing

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, broccolijs

I have cloned my ember project, use following commands

```
npm install
bower install

ember build
```

and got this message

> DEPRECATION: Brocfile.js has been deprecated in favor of
>   ember-cli-build.js. Ple ase see the transition guide:
>   https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/blob/master
>   /TRANSITION.md#user-content-brocfile-transition. The loader.js addon
>   is missing from your project, please add it to `package.json`.

I have searched about this exception and tried to install loader.js manually, but after this another got another exception :

> can't find module rsvp

It seems there is some global problem in my project, I can't determine what is it.

And about deprecation - brocfile.js, I haven't changed it, should I?

Comment: You might be on an older version of ember-cli? Maybe upgrading might help.

Comment: I have install ember to my machine yesterday. Do you mean old version of ember in my project?

Answer (score 4):

The global installed ember-cli is just a simple shim that calls the ember-cli version of the project.

It looks like your have an really old version of ember and ember-cli in your project. I would recommend to update this, and follow the transition guides.

For this follow the guide [here](http://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#upgrading). At the moment the current ember-cli version is `2.3.0`.

After `ember init` you have clean `bower.json` and `package.json` for your project. I personally like to replace all files and later use a git diff to get my custom code into the fresh files.

For this brocfile thing, just follow the guide! If you have no customizations in your brocfile you can just delete your brocfile and use the fresh `ember-cli-build.js`. If you have customizations you have to move them to the `ember-cli-build.js` into the default export function.

Comment: So, I should remove package.json and bower.js  files and recreate them later?

Comment: No. Follow the Guide. `ember init` will ask you to replace them and offer a diff. There you need to merge your customizations into the new blueprint.

Comment: Ah, understand what you mean. thanks.   
 I am following upgrading tutorial but 'rm' commnad is not recognized, any ides?

Comment: You are not on unix right? Use the powershell on windows. Or just delete the folders. `rm` is remove dir.

Comment: Uhu, I have updated and gotting some exceptions :/ for example
Assertion Failed: Using `{{view}}` or any path based on it ('scripts/templates/currency-text.hbs' @ L1:C0) has been removed in Ember 2.0

Comment: You did a long jump. Check the ember 2.0 changelog. Maybe just jump to Ember 1.13 first and then upgrade to 2.0 in  a second step.